# Lightning Component - Detect Data Change from Another Source

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, field-service-lightning

I've built a lightning component that receives a ServiceAppointment (Field Service Lightning) record from a parent component, and leveraging this component to face a VisualForce page via an `<iframe>` element. The component in question is also leveraging `force:recordData` for some additional benefits, such as its built in `recordUpdated` listener.

Here's a simplified version of this component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="serviceAppointment" type="ServiceAppointment" required="true" />
    <aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="ServiceAppointment" required="true" />

    <force:recordData aura:id="forceRecord"
                  recordId="{!v.serviceAppointment.Id}" 
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  targetRecord="{!v.serviceAppointment}"
                  targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
                  recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdated}"
                  fields="Id,AppointmentNumber,FSL__Scheduling_Policy_Used__c,Has_Resource_Assigned__c,Status" />

    <iframe src="{!'<company url>/apex/FSL__GetCandidates?id=' + v.simpleRecord.Id}" />
</aura:component>
```

Once an action happens in the `FSL__GetCandidates` VisualForce page, the `Has_Resource_Assigned__c` field has its value updated accordingly through an apex trigger with the idea the `force:recordData` component will pick up the change. However, the `recordUpdated` listener never fires, likely because the change happened from outside the scope of the component.

I already looked into `lightning:empApi` and saw ServiceAppointment isn't supported at this time.

Nothing short of building a listener that pings the server every N seconds, is there an option in Salesforce that is more streamlined?

Note: The VisualForce page FSL__GetCandidates is from the Field Service Lightning managed package so I have no access to its logic. Also, this component does not sit on a record page.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get everything wired up leveraging `lightning:empApi` and a [Platform Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_intro.htm) while moving away from the `force:recordData` concept.

Below is a working example that anyone can leverage with some subtle changes.

### Step 1 - Create Platform Event

- From Setup, search for `Platform Events` under `Integrations`. For me the API name is `Service_Appointment_Resource_Update__e`.
- Create a new Platform Event and any custom fields you may need.

### Step 2 - Publish New Platform Event

This can be done from apex anonymous for testing purposes, but the following is an example in a trigger:

```
Map<Id, ServiceAppointment> serviceAppointmentMap = new Map<Id, ServiceAppointment>();
Map<Id, Service_Appointment_Resource_Update__e> notificationsToPublish = new Map<Id, Service_Appointment_Resource_Update__e>();
List<AssignedResource> assignedResources = Trigger.isInsert
    ? Trigger.New
    : Trigger.Old;

for (AssignedResource res : assignedResources) {
    serviceAppointmentMap.put(res.ServiceAppointmentId, null);
}

serviceAppointmentMap.remove(null);

for (ServiceAppointment sa : [SELECT Id, Has_Resource_Assigned__c FROM ServiceAppointment WHERE Id IN :serviceAppointmentMap.keySet()]) {
    sa.Has_Resource_Assigned__c = Trigger.isInsert;//note: if this trigger becomes expanded upon this will require being more flushed out

    notificationsToPublish.put(sa.Id, new Service_Appointment_Resource_Update__e(Message__c = 'Service Resource Changed', Is_Resource_Assigned__c = sa.Has_Resource_Assigned__c, Service_Appointment_Id__c = sa.Id));

    serviceAppointmentMap.put(sa.Id, sa);
}

if (!serviceAppointmentMap.isEmpty()) {
    update serviceAppointmentMap.values();

    EventBus.publish(notificationsToPublish.values());//publish all events
}
```

### Step 3 - Create Lightning Component to Subscribe to Platform Event

**Component.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="channel" type="String" default="/event/Service_Appointment_Resource_Update__e"/>
    <aura:attribute name="subscription" type="Map"/>
    <aura:attribute name="serviceAppointments" type="ServiceAppointment[]" />

    <lightning:empApi aura:id="empApi"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
<aura:component/>
```

**ComponentController.js**

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set('v.subscription', null);
    // Get empApi component.
    const empApi = component.find('empApi');
    // Define an error handler function that prints the error to the console.
    const errorHandler = function (message) {
        console.error('Received error ', JSON.stringify(message));
    };
    // Register empApi error listener and pass in the error handler function.
    empApi.onError($A.getCallback(errorHandler));
    helper.subscribe(component, event, helper);

    helper.handleInit(component, event, helper);
}
```

**ComponentHelper.js**

```
({
    // Client-side function that invokes the subscribe method on the
    // empApi component.
    subscribe: function (component, event, helper) {
        // Get the empApi component.
        const empApi = component.find('empApi');
        // Get the channel from the attribute.
        const channel = component.get('v.channel');
        // Subscription option to get only new events.
        const replayId = -1;
        // Callback function to be passed in the subscribe call.
        // After an event is received, this callback prints the event
        // payload to the console. A helper method displays the message
        // in the console app.
        const callback = function (message) {
            console.log('Event Received : ' + JSON.stringify(message));
            helper.onReceiveNotification(component, message);
        };
        // Subscribe to the channel and save the returned subscription object.
        empApi.subscribe(channel, replayId, $A.getCallback(callback)).then($A.getCallback(function (newSubscription) {
            console.log('Subscribed to channel ' + channel);
            component.set('v.subscription', newSubscription);
        }));
    },
    // Client-side function that invokes the unsubscribe method on the
    // empApi component.
    unsubscribe: function (component, event, helper) {
        // Get the empApi component.
        const empApi = component.find('empApi');
        // Get the channel from the component attribute.
        const channel = component.get('v.subscription').channel;
        // Callback function to be passed in the unsubscribe call.
        const callback = function (message) {
            console.log('Unsubscribed from channel ' + message.channel);
        };
        // Unsubscribe from the channel using the subscription object.        
        empApi.unsubscribe(component.get('v.subscription'), $A.getCallback(callback));
    },
    // Client-side function that displays the platform event message
    // in the console app and displays a toast if not muted.
    onReceiveNotification: function (component, message) {
        // Extract notification from platform event
        const newNotification = {
            time: $A.localizationService.formatDateTime(
                message.data.payload.CreatedDate, 'HH:mm'),
            message: message.data.payload.Message__c,
            serviceAppointmentId: message.data.payload.Service_Appointment_Id__c,
            isResourceAssigned: message.data.payload.Is_Resource_Assigned__c
        };

        let serviceAppointments = component.get("v.serviceAppointments");

        serviceAppointments.forEach((sa) => {
            if (newNotification.serviceAppointmentId == sa.Id) {
                sa.Has_Resource_Assigned__c = newNotification.isResourceAssigned;
            }
        });

        component.set("v.serviceAppointments", serviceAppointments);
    }
})
```

[This Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/workshop-platform-events) was the walkthrough that finally got me on the right path. The `Change Capture Data` methodology is not necessary. So everyone knows, the wait time is almost nonexistent and is far more lightweight and reliable than `cometd` appeared to be.